# Matching one tokenized set with many others

Tags: python, mapreduce, nlp

I have a data quering problem and am a little stuck as to how to solve it. I have a 2 lists of urls. One, we can call 'positive hits', and another called 'unknown hits'. The goal is to tokenize each sets of pages and find any matching tokens in the unknown set of urls with the positive set of urls. For example, if the first url in the positive set has the token 'hello' found on it, that token should be checked against the tokenized versions of all unknown url pages (in tokenized form) to see if there is a hit. Then move on to the second url in the positive set... etc.

I can tokenize the pages no problem and even do an intersection for each page in the positive url sets with every page in the unknown set but this is very slow. Is there another method of computation i can use to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I know what you're intending to do, but it sounds like using set arithmetic would work.

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
intersection = set1 & set2
if intersection:
    # there's an intersection
    list_intersection = sorted(list(intersection))
else:
    # there's no intersection
```